# GetTickCount function

Tags: c, time, gettickcount

I have a question regarding GetTickCount function,
I have two calls to this function in my code with several commands between them and the function in both calls returns same count.
i.e.

```
var1 = GetTickCount();
code
:
:
var2 = GetTickCount();
```

var1 and var2 has same values in it.

can someone help?

Comment: This may be helpful: http://capnbry.net/blog/?p=44

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Assuming this is the Windows [GetTickCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724408(VS.85).aspx) call, that's entirely reasonable:

> The resolution of the GetTickCount
>   function is limited to the resolution
>   of the system timer, which is
>   typically in the range of 10
>   milliseconds to 16 milliseconds.

Note that it's only measuring *milliseconds* to start with - and you can do an awful lot in a millisecond these days.

The docs go on to say:

> If you need a higher resolution timer,
>   use a [multimedia timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743609(v=VS.85).aspx) or a
>   [high-resolution timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644900(v=VS.85).aspx).

Perhaps [`QueryPerformanceCounter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904(v=VS.85).aspx) would be more appropriate?

Comment: @johan Skeet but what does mean by resolution of system timer in this way ?

Comment: @Miss: You can think of it as "how often the clock ticks" effectively.

Answer (score 7):

If you are referring to the Windows API call then read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724408(VS.85).aspx).
I would guess that you are trying to time a short interval so this paragraph is relevant. Are you timing something shorter than that interval? If so look into QueryPerformanceCounter instead perhaps.

> The resolution of the GetTickCount
>   function is limited to the resolution
>   of the system timer, which is
>   typically in the range of 10
>   milliseconds to 16 milliseconds. The
>   resolution of the GetTickCount
>   function is not affected by
>   adjustments made by the
>   GetSystemTimeAdjustment function.

Answer (score 5):

If you go the QueryPerformanceCounter route you need to watch out for hardware dependent [wierdness](http://web.archive.org/web/20070118175020/http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;EN-US;Q274323&). Its been awhile so I don't know if this kinda stuff still happens.

You might also want to take a [look at this link](http://web.archive.org/web/20101223104030/http://developer.nvidia.com/object/timer_function_performance.html) since it has a nice sample app which compares QueryPerformanceCounter, GetTickCount  and TimeGetTime

Comment: Unfortunately the link to Nvidia isn't valid anymore. Has somebody found an alternative source?

Comment: @blerontin I updated the links. The second one is using the web archive . It was 5 years ago so it might not work on current hardware.

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724408%28VS.85%29.aspx)

> The resolution of the GetTickCount
>   function is limited to the resolution
>   of the system timer, which is
>   typically in the range of 10
>   milliseconds to 16 milliseconds. The
>   resolution of the GetTickCount 
>   function is not affected by
>   adjustments made by the
>   GetSystemTimeAdjustment  function.
>
> The elapsed time is stored as a DWORD
>   value. Therefore, the time will wrap
>   around to zero if the system is run
>   continuously for 49.7 days. To avoid
>   this problem, use the GetTickCount64
>   function. Otherwise, check for an
>   overflow condition when comparing
>   times.
>
> If you need a higher resolution timer,
>   use a multimedia timer or a
>   high-resolution timer.

Answer (score 1):

GetTickCount has a resolution of one millisecond (in practice, it's several milliseconds). It's highly likely that the functions you're calling in between are taking considerably less than 1 millisecond.

Comment: Actually even worse: around 10ms resolution